# Passing a class instance to another instance via constructors in C++

Tags: c++

I have a question about passing class instances to each other in C++, my question includes 3 parts. Assume this example:

```
struct A{
 int num;
};

struct B{
 int num;
 B(A input) : num(input.num){}
};
```

#### 1:

```
int main(){
 //
 return 0;
}
```

Here constructor of `B` takes in `input.num` even though `input.num` is not even initialized yet.
I guess this is ok so far since no instance of either class is even created yet correct?
The compiler doesn't even generate code for the class functions. `num` being not initialized doesn't matter since technically it doesn't even exist yet?

#### 2:

Now what if I make an instance of them but still don't initialize `num` in `A`:

```
int main(){
 A a;
 B b(a);
 return 0;
}
```

Here `num` is still not initialized, is this going to cause `undefined behaviour`?
When the constructor of `B` tries to read it?

#### 3:

Final example of the question will be:

```
int main(){
 A a = {5};
 B b(a);
 return 0;
}
```

Here `a` is fully initialized and this should have a normal execution correct?

Comment: _"Here constructor of B takes in input.num even though input.num is not even initialized yet"_ that's not entirely true. `input` is a copy of the `A` you pass in, so if `num` is initialized in that, it'll be initialized here too. If it isn't, then it will be uninitialized here too.

Comment: but that will fall into example 2 and 3 right? in 1 none of the classes are even used yet? main function is empty.

Comment: The copying of `a` in the constructor in example 2 makes it undefined behavior. In 3), the copying of `a` is ok since it's initialized, so no problem.

Comment: @Dan yeah, you're pretty much right about points 2 and 3, I believe. Just that that sentence is a bit misleading in the beginning.

Comment: Almost correct. The UB in 2) happens before `B` tries to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The constructor of B takes as an input argument an object of type `A`. In this snippet, we see the definition of the structures/classes, thus no object is created, neither of type `A` nor of type `B`.
2. This will be undefined behavior, since `a` is not initialized when it's copied into `input`.
3. This is a properly initialized code with c++11 and above (due to extended initializer lists), nothing is undefined.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 thanks for the comment, I added clarification.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. So in example 1, `num(input.num){}` is not even called, since no object is even created yet, which means there are no issues with having a member uninitialized.

Comment: Sorry wanted to clarify if my comment above is correct?

Comment: As long as an object is not instantiated, there is no case of initialized/uninitialized member. You may think of the struct definition as a type declaration. No object is created until you instantiate one.